# Render page with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, actioncontroller

I'm trying to make "friendship" between model Programme and Student. I do it with has_many :through model Relationship. In Relationship controller I have create action, which should redirect another page after the friendship occurs.

So, in Student show view I have link_to request friendship. I thought I will be able to enter Student show page, but instead it redirects me from Student index when I try to enter Student show view to another page. So I actually can't enter Student show, it just redirects me to other page.

Why is that happening? I want have redirect from Student show view after I click on "request friendship" to other model page.

Student show.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to "Request friendship with #{@student.name}",
 { :controller => "relationship", :action => "create",
 :id => @student.name },
 :confirm => "Send friend request to #{@student.name}?" %>
```

route.rb

```
 match "/students/:id" => "relationships#create"
```

UPDATED

Relationship controller

```
def create
  Relationship.request(@prog, @student)
  flash[:notice] = "Friend request sent."
  redirect_to prog_url
end
```

rake routes

```
    relationships_create GET    /relationships/create(.:format)   relationships#create
    relationships_destroy GET    /relationships/destroy(.:format)  relationships#destroy
                         /students/:id(.:format)           relationships#create
    relationships GET    /relationships(.:format)          relationships#index
                  POST   /relationships(.:format)          relationships#create
 new_relationship GET    /relationships/new(.:format)      relationships#new
edit_relationship GET    /relationships/:id/edit(.:format) relationships#edit
     relationship GET    /relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#show
                  PUT    /relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#update
                  DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)      relationships#destroy
         students GET    /students(.:format)               students#index
                  POST   /students(.:format)               students#create
      new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)           students#new
     edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)      students#edit
          student GET    /students/:id(.:format)           students#show
                  PUT    /students/:id(.:format)           students#update
                  DELETE /students/:id(.:format)           students#destroy
            progs GET    /progs(.:format)                  progs#index
                  POST   /progs(.:format)                  progs#create
         new_prog GET    /progs/new(.:format)              progs#new
        edit_prog GET    /progs/:id/edit(.:format)         progs#edit
             prog GET    /progs/:id(.:format)              progs#show
                  PUT    /progs/:id(.:format)              progs#update
                  DELETE /progs/:id(.:format)              progs#destroy
```

Comment: post your controller and tell us where you want to be redirected

Comment: I want it to be redirected to prog model index page

Comment: can you run rake routes and post the result?

Comment: does `redirect_to @prog` work what you want to?

Comment: it gives cannot redirect to nil

Comment: well actually yes. Where do you set up the `@prog` variable? you have to set it somehow

Comment: I added var @prog to create action in Relationship, right? After I get redirected to Prog index page, however I somehow skip Student show view and get redirected directly to Prog index.

Comment: I want to be redirected from Student show after I initiate request for friendship

Comment: yes yes, but you are not setting up the `@prog` and `@student` variables

Comment: I don't get. Can you give an example how I'm not setting up vars?

Comment: wouldn't you have to be on the programme page to add the request? how do you know which programme you are trying to be-friend?

Comment: ok, now I understand what problem is about. thanks!

Comment: need further help? Guy wrote it down pretty much as it is

Comment: little guidance always is appreciated! If I stuck I'll ask to navigate right way, but so far I'm fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand completely what @prog should be, but this is the way to go

```
def create
  @student = Student.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @prog = Programme.find_by_id(params[:prog]) #You need to fill this in
  Relationship.request(@prog, @student)
  flash[:notice] = "Friend request sent."
  redirect_to @student # Or @prog, or whatever you'd like
end
```

*You would probably need to pass the prog.id as well to the controller something like:*

`match "/students/:id/:prog" => "relationships#create"`

and add

```
<%= link_to "Request friendship with #{@student.name}",
 { :controller => "relationship", :action => "create",
:id => @student.name, :prog => @student.current_programme },
# I don't know how you differ programmes, you'd have to work this one out  
:confirm => "Send friend request to #{@student.name}?" %>
```